# Convert factor to number with this command correct

Tags: r, type-conversion

Im trying to convert the following factor to number in RStudio, can I use this commands?

`NewFactor <- factor(c(31, 764, 9.6, 513, 125.344, 3131.657, 9853));as.numeric(NewFactor)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need to convert it to `character` and then to `numeric`

```
new <- as.numeric(as.character(NewFactor))
new
#[1]   31.000  764.000    9.600  513.000  125.344 3131.657 9853.000
is.numeric(new)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or a faster

```
new <- as.numeric(levels(NewFactor)[NewFactor])
new
#[1]   31.000  764.000    9.600  513.000  125.344 3131.657 9853.000
```

because by directly applying `as.numeric`, the numbers that we get are the integer storage mode values